# Getting sum of total value from Reduce

Tags: reactjs, array-reduce

I  have 3 label that can receive input when button clicked
and then i need sum from the third input value
the code kinda work
but instead of getting the sum of the third input it instead it looks like the image below where the input get combined kinda like a string (not sure how to call it).
Any help is appreciated
[What Total looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz3VQ.png)

This is my full code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import './Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css';


class App extends Component { 
  constructor(){ 
    super(); 
 
    this.state = { 
      mahasiswa : [], 
      tgl : null,
      nama : null, 
      nilai : null,
      nilaiArray: []
    }   
  
  } 
 
  setValueState(event){ 
    var value = event.target.value
    this.setState({ 
      [event.target.name] : value
    }) 
    var nilaiArrayTmp = this.state.nilaiArray;
    nilaiArrayTmp.push(value?parseFloat(value).toFixed(2):0)
    this.setState({
      nilaiArray: nilaiArrayTmp
    })
  }

  addData(){ 
    var data_tmp = this.state.mahasiswa;     
    data_tmp.push({nim : this.state.tgl, nama : this.state.nama, nilai : this.state.nilai}); 
    this.setState({ 
      mahasiswa : data_tmp 
    }) 
    
    
    
  } 
  
   
  render() { 
    const total=(this.state.mahasiswa.reduce((total,{nilai}) =>  total = total + nilai , 0 ));

    return (       
        <div className="container"> 
            <h2><b>Daftar Pengeluaran</b></h2>
            <div className="form-container"> 
                <div className="form-group"> 
                    <label>Waktu:</label> 
                    <input type="text" name="tgl" value={this.state.tgl} onChange={this.setValueState.bind(this)} className="form-control" /> 
                </div> 
                <div className="form-group"> 
                    <label>Deskripsi:</label> 
                    <input type="text" name="nama" value={this.state.nama} onChange={this.setValueState.bind(this)} className="form-control" /> 
                </div> 
                <div className="form-group"> 
                    <label>Jumlah:</label> 
                    <input type="number" name="nilai" value={this.state.nilai} onChange={this.setValueState.bind(this)} className="form-control" /> 
                </div> 
                <br />
                <button onClick={this.addData.bind(this)} type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Tambah</button> 
            </div>
            <br /> 
            <table className="table"> 
                <thead>      
                    <tr>
                        <th>No.</th>
                        <th>Waktu</th>
                        <th>Deskripsi</th>
                        <th>Jumlah</th>
                    </tr> 
                </thead> 
                <tbody> 
                    {this.state.mahasiswa.map((mhs, index)=>( 
                    <tr key={index}> 
                        <td>{index+1}</td>
                        <td>{mhs.tgl}</td> 
                        <td>{mhs.nama}</td>
                        <td>{mhs.nilai}</td>
                    </tr> 
                    ))} 
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Total:</td>
                        <td>{total}</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody> 
            </table>
        </div> 
    ); 
    } 
  };
  
export default App;
```

Comment: Unrelated to the totaling issue but you have a state mutation issue in both the `setValueState` and `addData` callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Input` bydefalult is inputting it as `string` and setting the state also as a `String`. Because of that `0+string` = `string` and you are getting a string.

Instead of adding to 0, it is converting 0 to a `string` and `concatenating` rest of the values to it.

You can use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` accordingly to use it as an `Integer` and get desired result.

```
const total=(this.state.mahasiswa.reduce((total,{nilai}) => total + parseInt(nilai) , 0 ));
```

Answer (score 1):

`parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)` returns a string type, not a number type

```
setValueState(event){ 
  var value = event.target.value
  this.setState({ 
    [event.target.name] : value
  }) 
  var nilaiArrayTmp = this.state.nilaiArray;
  nilaiArrayTmp.push(value?parseFloat(value).toFixed(2):0) // <-- converted back to string type!
  this.setState({
    nilaiArray: nilaiArrayTmp
  })
}
```

so in the array reduce callback you are doing string concatenation. To resolve, convert the values back to a number time for addition. Don't mutate the `total` value being returned, just return the current `total` value plus the next `nilai` value.

```
const total = this.state.mahasiswa.reduce(
  (total, { nilai }) => total + Number(nilai),
  0
);
```

#### The state mutations

In both the `setValueState` and `addData` handlers you are mutating the state object but directly pushing into the arrays.

```
setValueState(event) { 
  var value = event.target.value
  this.setState({ 
    [event.target.name] : value
  }) 
  var nilaiArrayTmp = this.state.nilaiArray; // <-- reference to state
  nilaiArrayTmp.push(value?parseFloat(value).toFixed(2):0) // <-- state mutation!!
  this.setState({
    nilaiArray: nilaiArrayTmp // <-- reference saved back into state
  })
}

addData(){ 
  var data_tmp = this.state.mahasiswa; // <-- reference to state
  data_tmp.push({ // <-- state mutation!!
    nim: this.state.tgl,
    nama: this.state.nama,
    nilai: this.state.nilai,
  }); 
  this.setState({ 
    mahasiswa: data_tmp // <-- reference saved back into state
  });
}
```

In both cases you should use a functional state update and return a new array reference.

```
setValueState(event) { 
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    [name]: value,
    nilaiArray: [
      ...prevState.nilaiArray,
      value ? Number(value).toFixed(2) : 0,
    ],
  }))
}

addData(){ 
  this.setState({ 
    mahasiswa: [
      ...prevState.mahasiswa,
      {
        nim: prevState.tgl,
        nama: prevState.nama,
        nilai: prevState.nilai,
      }
    ], 
  });
}
```